# Battery percentage in system tray

Tags: windows, battery, icon

I have been looking for a long while for a utility that displays the current battery percentage **in the system tray**, not as a toolbar like [BatteryBar Pro](https://batterybarpro.com/). I use a vertically-oriented taskbar and toolbars like BatteryBar mess with the taskbar's width. I've looked at other system tray utilities, but none of them have an option to show battery percentage. Does such a program exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was given an answer on [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/software/comments/5356i5/utility_to_show_battery_percentage_in_system_tray/) that says:

1. Install and/or open [HWiNFO](https://www.hwinfo.com/).
2. Open the Sensors view if it isn't already shown by clicking on the button labeled "Sensors".
3. Select "Configure Sensors" (gear icon in lower right of sensors window) and navigate to the "System Tray" tab.
4. Scroll down until you find your battery. Underneath the battery should be an option that says "Charge Level". Select it, then check "Show in Tray".
5. (Optional) Configure custom settings such as colors to your liking.

**NOTE**: It is recommended to have HWiNFO start up automatically to ensure that this meter is always present. This among other options are available in the main settings.